# Why is there an unrecognized rule in my flex code?

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex

**My Problems are  my rules**

This code must detect an URL from a file in this form:

`ftp://[<user>[:<password>]@]<host>[:<port>]/<path>[;<ftptype>]`.

I already updated homebrew and flex. I was compiling using "flex example.flex", and trying to execute using "./a.out file.txt"

My Rules:

```
LETRA [A-Za-z]
DIG [0-9]
CAR {"_"|"$"}
IDENT {LETRA|"$"|"_"}({LETRA|DIG|"_"|"$"|"-"}*)

%%
{LETRA}({LETRA|DIG}{3,})({LETRA}|{DIG}*) {
                                          printf("(<user>,%s)",yytext);
                                         }
{LETRA}{CAR}({LETRA|DIG|CAR}{4,})({LETRA|DIG|CAR}*)|
{LETRA}{LETRA|DIG}{CAR}({LETRA|DIG|CAR}{3,})|
{LETRA}({LETRA|DIG}{2}){CAR}{LETRA|DIG|CAR}{2,}|
{LETRA}({LETRA|DIG}{3}){CAR}({LETRA|DIG|CAR}+)|
{LETRA}({LETRA|DIG}{4}){CAR}({LETRA|DIG|CAR}*)|
{LETRA}({LETRA|DIG}{5}){CAR}({LETRA|DIG|CAR}*)  {printf("(<password>,%s)",yytext);}
({IDENT[.]}+{IDENT})+ {
                        printf("(<host>,%s)",yytext);
                      }
{DIG}({DIG})* {
                printf("(<port>,%s)",yytext);
              }
({IDENT[/]}+{IDENT})+ {
                       printf("(<path>,%s)",yytext);
                      }
{[#]DIG}({DIG})* {
                  printf("(<ftptype>,%s)",yytext);
                 }
. {printf("%s",yytext);}
%%


int main(){
   yylex();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a starting point: "{" "}" are  not being used correctly -- it should be

- `{id}` to expand a user-class `id`
- `REGEXP{number}` or `REXEXP{number,number}` for numeric quantification

When you wrote:

```
CAR {"_"|"$"}
```

it should be `CAR ("_"|"$")` or `CAR  [_$]`

```
IDENT {LETRA|"$"|"_"}({LETRA|DIG|"_"|"$"|"-"}*)
```

should be:

```
IDENT ({LETRA}|"$"|"_")({LETRA}|{DIG}|"_"|"$"|"-")*
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is because of:

```
{LETRA}({LETRA|DIG}{3,})({LETRA}|{DIG}*) {
```

You can't combine user-classes (not sure if that's the official name) with |, it has to be:

```
{LETRA}(({LETRA}|{DIG}){3,})({LETRA}|{DIG}*) {
```